# kendo grid rows are rendered with default style

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My grid is

```
                      @(Html.Kendo().Grid<student.Models.SearchViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "studentGrid" })
    .Columns(
                x =>
                {
                    x.Bound(y => y.Id).Hidden(true);
                    x.Bound(y => y.Id).ClientTemplate(@"<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='#= Id #' class='mainCheckbox' onclick='checkboxClicked(this, ""checkAllMain"")'/>")
                        .Title("")
                        .HeaderTemplate(@"<input type='checkbox' name='checkAllMain' onclick='selectAll(this, ""mainCheckbox"");' />")
                        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" })
                        .Filterable(false)
                        .Sortable(false)
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "checboxClass", style = "text-align:center" });
                    x.Bound(y => y.abc1).Hidden(false);
                    x.Bound(y => y.abc2).Hidden(false);
                    x.Bound(y => y.abc3).Hidden(false);
                }
    )
        .ToolBar(tb =>
        {
            tb.Custom()
                .Text("Export To Excel")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "export" })
                .Url(Url.Action("Export", Html.CurrentControllerName()));
            tb.Custom()
                .Text("Expand Selected Rows")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "expandSelectedRows" });
        })
        .Groupable()
        .Reorderable(x => x.Columns(true))
        .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new int[] { 20, 50, 100 }).Input(true).Numeric(true))
        .Scrollable(x => x.Enabled(true).Height(Model.Height))
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable()
        .Navigatable()
        .Filterable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("subTemplate")
        .AutoBind(!Model.NoAutoload)
                .Events(ev => { ev.DataBound("DataBoundSearch"); })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax().PageSize(100)
        .ServerOperation(false) // Paging, sorting, filtering and grouping will be done client-side
        .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Id))
                .Events(events => events.Error("error").RequestStart("RequestStart").RequestEnd("RequestEnd").Change("Changed"))
                .Read(x => x.Action("GetData", Html.CurrentControllerName()).Data("ABCPostData")))       
    )
```

with kendo grid when we select a row that row is highlighted with brown color by default.Am not able to get the default color when row is clicked. On the client side it rendered as

```
       <tr class="k-master-row k-state-selected" data-uid="122bb914-87c2-4f0c-9351-52c1d9b84ae5" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

how it is set to background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); ? how can i override this to brown like background-color: #f0713a, border-color: #f0713a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The easiest way is through CSS

**Modifying style for selected row**

```
#grid tr.k-state-selected td {
   background-color: #f0713a;
   border-color: #f0713a
}
```

**Modifying style for selected cell**

```
#grid td.k-state-selected {
   background-color: #f0713a;
   border-color: #f0713a
}
```

and in your grid declaration ensure this is set:

```
selectable: "cell"
```

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexyu/EcC4Q/) for single cell.

---

Another way is to override kendo styles with their [themebuilder](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/themebuilder/web.html). But this is extremely bulky.

If you want to do it programatically, this is possible too by getting the selected element in the `change` event of the grid, and then setting the element's background in code. I will try to do this if you need this option, but the way I see it, leave UI stuff to css, and leave coding to javascript.